# AWS SAM/Cloudformation for multi environment - convert comma delimited list to ARNs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam, aws-lambda-layers

I am working with AWS SAM to generate infra code for a multi-environment setup. I want to use the same template.yaml file for dev/test/prod with a separate configuration file (i.e samconfig.yaml).
How do I assign existing layer ARNs to a lambda function as these layers have different names and versions?

SAM template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Parameters:
  Client:
    Type: String
  Stage:
    Type: String
  Layers:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub ${Client}-${Stage}-lambda
      Layers:
        # - !Sub 'arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:layer:request-layer:2'
```

samconfig.toml:

```
version = 0.1
[default]
[default.deploy]
[default.deploy.parameters]
.
.
.
parameter_overrides = "Layers=\"request-layer:2,pandas-layer:5\""
```

My approach is to have a comma-delimited parameter which I would like to convert into an ARN list using intrinsic functions but I can't.

Comment: "but I can't." - is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any errors?

Comment: i don't know how to use intrinsic functions to create the qualifying arn from a list

Comment: I don't understand your question. And yes I am unclear as this is all new to me. I wanted to save layer names in the config file and convert it to arns in template.yaml using either Fn::Join or Fn::Split or something (`parameter_overrides` requires a string value which makes it uncomfortable to save long arns in config file). Please provide a solution if any.

Comment: As I wrote, you can't do this. Its not possible without a [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html). So you have to develop the macro suited to your needs.

Comment: No. seems to me like a lot of work for such a small thing. just added the arns directly to the .toml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Layers` is your parameter of type `CommaDelimitedList`, you can use it as follows:

```
Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub ${Client}-${Stage}-lambda
      Layers: !Ref Layers
```

Comment: I will have to specify the complete layer arn (with accountid and region hardcoded). I don't want to do that since my environments are in different aws accounts.

Comment: @SankalpTambe Yes. There is no other way unless you create your own cloudformation macro.

Comment: accepting this answer as no solution other than a macro.